# Configure Azure Linux VM to allow connection from outside (TCP Port 3000)

Tags: node.js, azure, bitnami, mean-stack

I have created a `linux` virtual machine (from bitnami MEAN 2.6 image) in Azure. I have added following as an end-point (in cloud service):

```
Name     Protocol    Public Port

node     TCP         3000
```

But when I run sample node application (on port 3000), I am not able to access http://mydomain.cloudapp.net from outside. Am I missing some configuration or need to do some change in `node`? Note that firewall is not running in VM (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Actually i am using VM(Oracle) .So i did port forwarding to access from outside..

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your point. I need to configure port forwarding for outside access? Any resources to learn that?

Comment: Hi I am facing the same problem. Were you able to solve it?